# Edges on image when converting html to pdf with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: html, css, pdf

I have been working on generating an html page to pdf using wkhtmltopdf. Everything is working fine besides one thing. There are edges to one of the images. There are a couple of other images that are working fine. I have been researching this quite a bit and there is not a lot out there on this. I have tried a couple of tweeks.

- making sure the image was an even height
- making sure the image pixels were even
- adding padding

[image: image with edge]

Comment: I can't see any edges on the images?

Comment: Look by the timeline - there are thin lines right above and right below that are not from the image itself. Those are being created when the html is converted to the pdf.

Comment: Are you able to include your CSS?